# Фильтровать данные между собой

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как отфильтровать данные между собой?

Есть `status.json`
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.9f445c216ad64d449264db22a749c57c

Есть массив `product`
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.47af6080e8dd414aafbd131c1a5c81b9

Если `viewStatus === grid` необходимо фильтровать массив `product` с данными `color` и `height` из `status.json`

Если `viewStatus === inline` необходимо фильтровать массив `product` с данными `color`, `size`, `capacity` из `status.json`

Я фильтрую `status.json` и получаю объекты

```
Object.entries(status).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
  if (key === variantValue.value) {
    value.accent.forEach(element => element.map(x => console.log(x)))
  }
})
```

Так же получаю отфильтрованные объекты из `product`

```
product.map(element => console.log(element))
```

Ожидаемый результат:

Если `viewStatus === grid`, то получаем такой объект https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.332befaf0c104e9e9042c5ec69e22410

Comment: брр. Два массива, а в примерах работа с объектам. И где сам вопрос, что именно не получается сделать? Приведите пример этих массивов, условия сравнения и ожидаемый результат

Comment: @SwaD Исправил пост

Comment: Понятней не стало, т.к. viewStatus не найден ни там ни там... Возможно viewStatus это некая переменная, которая является ключом объекта, тогда значение слова фильтровать - это вывести данные из массива, которые соответствуют критериям или просто вывести все?

Comment: @SwaD Верно, вывести данные из массива, в зависимости от viewStatus (это некая переменная, которая просто существует, допустим viewStatus = grid), то есть если у нас `viewStatus === grid`, то мы получаем из массива product, только type-and-sugar и region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать задачу в лоб и нет подводных камней в виде нескольких элементов/объектов одного типа, то  можно решить так

```js
const obj = {
    "grid" : {
        "accent" : [
            [
                {
                    "color" : "property"
                },
                {
                    "height" : "property"
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "inline" : {
        "accent" : [
            [
                {
                    "color" : "property"
                },
                {
                    "size" : "property"
                },
                {
                    "capacity" : "property"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}

const arr = [
    [
        "size",
        {
            "name":"Size",
            "code":"size",
            "propertiesList":[
                {
                    "value":"50",
                    "code":"50sm"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        "capacity",
        {
            "name":"Capacity",
            "code":"capacity",
            "propertiesList":[
                {
                    "value":"0.75",
                    "code":"750ml"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        "height",
        {
            "name":"Height",
            "code":"height",
            "propertiesList":[
                {
                    "value":"Low",
                    "code":"low"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        "color",
        {
            "name":"Color",
            "code":"color",
            "propertiesList":[
                {
                    "value":"Red",
                    "code":"red"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
];

function select(name) {
    const res = {}
    res[name] = {
        accent: [[]]
    }
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < obj[name].accent[0].length; i++) {
        data.push(obj[name].accent[0][i])
    }
    data = data.map((item) => {
        return Object.keys(item);
    })
    data.forEach((itemData, indexData) => {
        arr.forEach((item) => {
            if (item[0] === itemData[0]) {
                res[name].accent[0].push({
                    [itemData]: item[1].propertiesList[0].value
                })
            }
        })
    })
    return res;
}

let name = 'grid';
console.log(1, select(name));
name = 'inline';
console.log(2, select(name));
```

Comment: А если, будет ещё один или более массивов внутри `accent`, то мне необходимо будет их объединить через flat?

Comment: Все значения из accent будут автоматом попадать в поиск и вытягиваться в результирующий объект. Однако, если в массиве propertiesList будет более 1 элемента, то данные добавятся только из первого. Так же, если значения искомого не будет, то и в результирующем объекте его не будет.